# Как импортировать файл по ссылке?

Tags: python

У меня есть задача прошерстить список из другого сайта (не парсерю, это мой файл из репозитория в гитхабе).

Есть ссылка на гитхаб (raw.githubusercontent.com/lolo02afon/test_forum/master/name.py), на странице по ссылке есть переменная со списком, я хочу ее импортировать

Comment: Если есть задача то нужно её решить!

Comment: Предыдущий комментатор как бы намекает, что из Вашего вопроса понятно чуть меньше, чем ничего. Больше подробностей в студию, ибо вопрос в том виде, в котором он сейчас, заслуживает закрытия. Добавьте: Ваш код, Ваш список, опишите, наконец, что по-Вашему значит "прошерстить"?

Comment: приношу извинения, но не знаю чего добавить. Есть ссылка на гитхаб (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lolo02afon/test_forum/master/name.py), на странице по ссылке есть переменная со списком, я хочу ее импортировать. Но как это сделать не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через `requests`, [как описано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744565/8324991). Я немного переделал код оттуда под ваш случай:

```
import requests
import ast

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lolo02afon/test_forum/master/name.py"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
x = ast.literal_eval(r.text)
print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
['Mari','Leonid','Max']
['Mari', 'Leonid', 'Max']
```

Можно легко преобразовать полученный текст в список `Python`. Но делать это лучше не встроенной функцией `eval` (которая исполняет код), а функцией пакета `ast.literal_eval` (которая парсит код), потому что прямо исполнять код, полученный со стороннего сайта, небезопасно, лучше никогда так не делать.

Comment: 1 - вместо `r.content.decode()` можно использовать `r.text`. 2 - я бы еще добавил, что полученную строку можно сконвертировать в список с помощь `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @insolor Я искал `text`, но пытался его взять от `context` и не нашёл, спасибо )